# JavaFX LineChart - ClassCastException because of the Axis' Type

Tags: java, javafx

How do I specify the axis type for the chart from the FXML file? It seems like the default types are `<String, Integer>`. If I declare my injectable field as `LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart`, and the I create a data series with `(Number, Number`), the program throws a `ClassCastException`.

It is mandatory for a FXML File to be used. The worst case scenario would be that I created my chart manually. My best guess is that this is a bug.

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class TestChart implements Initializable
{

    // ====================== 2. Instance Fields =============================

    @FXML
    private LineChart<Number, Number> testChart;

    private AnchorPane anchorPane;


    // ==================== 4. Constructors ====================

    public TestChart()
    {
        final FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader( TestChart.class.getResource("testChart.fxml") );
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try
        {
            anchorPane = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load();
        }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    // ==================== 5. Creators ====================

    @Override
    public void initialize(final URL arg0, final ResourceBundle arg1)
    {
        //      testChart.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
        //      testChart.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(true);

        testChart.getData().add(getDummyData());
    }


    // ==================== 7. Getters & Setters ====================

    public AnchorPane getAnchorPane()
    {
        return anchorPane;
    }


    // ==================== 13. Utility Methods ====================

    private XYChart.Series getDummyData()
    {
        final XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(1, 23)); // Works for ("1", 23)
        //      series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2", 14));
        //      series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("3", 15));
        //      series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("4", 24));
        //      series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("5", 34));
        //      series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("6", 36));
        //      series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("7", 22));
        //      series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("8", 45));
        //      series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("9", 43));
        //      series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("10", 17));
        //      series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("11", 29));
        //      series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("12", 25));

        return series;
    }
}
```

---

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis.invalidateRange(CategoryAxis.java:399)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.updateAxisRange(XYChart.java:603)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.layoutChartChildren(XYChart.java:620)
at javafx.scene.chart.Chart$1.layoutChildren(Chart.java:84)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1018)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem ? Because i'm suffering about this problem.

Comment: Can you show the FXML?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works fine for me. I tested with the following FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>

<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <LineChart fx:id="testChart">
    <xAxis><NumberAxis /></xAxis>
    <yAxis><NumberAxis /></yAxis>
    </LineChart>
</AnchorPane>
```

and test application:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            TestChart chart = new TestChart();
            Scene scene = new Scene(chart.getAnchorPane(), 600, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It's a little difficult to tell why you are getting a `ClassCastException` without seeing your FXML file (and in particular the axes you are using). However, from the stack trace, it appears you are using a `CategoryAxis`, which is not type-compatible with a `LineChart<Number, Number>`.

In general, you can declare the two data types (one for x and one for y) to be any types you want. Since you've declared

```
@FXML
private LineChart<Number, Number> testChart ;
```

both the type of the x variable and the type of the y variable are `Number`.

Referring to the [Javadocs for `LineChart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/LineChart.html), a `LineChart<X,Y>` requires an `Axis<X>` for the x-axis and an `Axis<Y>` for the y-axis. So you need an `Axis<Number>` for each axis. A `CategoryAxis` is an `Axis<String>` (again, refer to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/CategoryAxis.html)), so it cannot be used as an axis for your line chart: the data type for the axis is incompatible with the data type for the chart.

If you tried the following in Java:

```
LineChart<Number, Number> testChart ;
testChart = new LineChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());
```

you would get a compile error. Since you're (presumably) initializing the axes in FXML, and FXML has no type checking, you get the `ClassCastException` at runtime instead.

One thing that would help your code is to use a properly typed `Series`:

```
private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> getDummyData()
{
    final XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series.setName("My portfolio");
    // ...
}
```

Now the compiler will check that the type of the `Series` matches the type of the chart, and the type of the `Data` matches the type of the `Series`. (So `series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("1", 23));` would give a compile error, rather than a runtime error.) Since you are creating the axes in FXML, you still have no type checking on those but I think the cause of the error would (perhaps) become clearer.

The fix is to use a `NumberAxis`, as in my example above, instead of your `CategoryAxis`. If you really want to use a `CategoryAxis` for the x-axis, the x values have to be `String`s, and so you need to declare the `LineChart` as a `LineChart<String, Number>`. Similarly you would make the `Series` a `Series<String, Number>`.

Comment: Hello James. What JavaFX version are you using here? Also, did you try all these combinations: number-number, string-number, number-string, string-string?

Comment: JDK 1.8.0_11. 
Maybe I don't understand the question. Since you declared the `LineChart` as `LineChart<Number, Number>` you can only hope to add data where both x and y are `Number`s, so trying to pass in `String` values doesn't make sense. Or are you trying to do something else? What axes are you using?

Comment: @James_D maybe he's trying to ask you about creating axis' without defining them on fxml. In some cases, we may build a chart that has dynamic axis' so it must be defined on application side and then pass its parameters to fxml.

Comment: There's no way to do that. The `LineChart` constructors all take parameters for the axes, and those axes are immutable. So when the chart is created, the axes must be specified. The type of the axis must match the corresponding type of the chart. So if you use a `CategoryAxis` (which is an `Axis<String>`) for the x-axis, you must have an `XYChart<String, Something>` of some kind (e.g. `LineChart<String, Number>`)

Comment: @James_D Although I left this alone a while ago, I appreciate the effort.